# Task Results into a Single list

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a method below in my WCF service:

```
public List<string> ProcessTask(IEnumerable<string> data)
{             
    var contentTasks = ..........
    List<string> contentWeb = new List<string>();

    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(contentTasks, tasks =>
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Trace.TraceError(task.Exception.GetBaseException().Message);
                continue;
            }

            if (task.Result == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(task.Result.Content))
            {
               continue;
            }

            contentWeb.Add(task.Result.Content);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I return the List of strings that have `Result.Content` from all
the tasks? These tasks are asynchronous tasks, so basically I have to wait until all tasks are done before I return the result.

Comment: Don't mention in vain the name of `Async` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of continuewhenall i had to use Task.WaitAll(contentTasks);

Answer (score 3):

You should return a `Task<List<string>>`:

```
public Task<List<string>> ProcessTasksAsync(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
    var contentTasks = ..........
    return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(contentTasks, tasks =>
    {
        var contentWeb = new List<string>(); // Build this in the continuation
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            // ...same code...

            contentWeb.Add(task.Result.Content);

        }
        return contentWeb; // Set the task's result here
    });
}
```

As this is a WCF service, you can use the `Task<T>` method to [implement an asynchronous method pair](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/30/how-to-implement-a-wcf-asynchronous-service-operation-with-task-lt-t-gt.aspx) by returning the `Task<T>` in the `Begin***` method, and unwrapping the `Task<T>` in the `End***` method.

This makes this method asynchronous in a proper manner.

Note that this is far easier in C# 5 using `async`/`await`:

```
public async Task<List<string>> ProcessTasksAsync(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
    var contentTasks = ..........

    await Task.WhenAll(contentTasks);

    var contentWeb = new List<string>(); // Build this in the continuation
    foreach (var task in contentTasks)
    { 
        // ...same code...

        contentWeb.Add(task.Result.Content);
    }

    return contentWeb;
}
```

Comment: can you return a task in WCF? or i need another wrapper method that calls this

Comment: @JustinHomes You can use a Task to make an async implementation (begin/end methods), though it's clunky at best in C# 4.  The generator for 4.5/VS2012 automatically handles Task<T> in WCF, though.

Comment: @JustinHomes See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/30/how-to-implement-a-wcf-asynchronous-service-operation-with-task-lt-t-gt.aspx

Comment: Instead of using `TaskCompletionSource`, you could return the list from the lambda and then directly return the `Task<List<string>>` that will be returned by `ContinueWhenAll()`.

Comment: @ReedCopsey there is a return inside a return? and is this my BeginDoWork method from the link example and i need to write a EndWork?

Comment: @JustinHomes Yes.  The return inside is returning from the lambda.  You would need to effectively wrap this inside of a BeginDoWork, and make an EndDoWork to extract the task.Result

Comment: @ReedCopsey Do you have a complete example? i am expecting my client to send me only list of data to my  method and return only list of content. but Endtask looks like gets called for each task and client gets task retrured. i'm kinda getting confused

Comment: @JustinHomes If you want a single call that returns the List, you'll need to block on the server.  You'd have to make this async (begin/end), and the end task returns the list.  Look at the link I said - it has a complete example.